# Having problem in dereferencing the vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, data-structures

I am creating a grid game in which each box in the grid is a district and represents some people along with their specific ID.

Now I have a function here which locates where the exact person is in the grid in particular box.

Here is my function.

```
bool where(int id, int &row, int &col)const
{
    person* per;
    for(int i=0;i<alive.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout<<alive[i]<<std::endl; //This is just for testing the person number
        if (alive[i]->person_id == id)
        {
            p = alive[i];
            break;              
        }
    }
}
```

**My Question:** The test code `std::cout<<alive[i]<<std::endl;` is always printing the address of the number. I tried many things but I couldn't figure it out.

**Edit:** Here `alive` is a vector

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: It might be worth telling us how `alive` is defined? Especially as that's the thing your question is about.

Comment: It is a vector, but how is it defined?

Comment: You know you can put different things in a vector? Can you tell us what things you put in this vector?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line in your code: `if (alive[i]->person_id == id)`. The fact that it uses `->` rather than `.` indicates that `alive` isn't a vector of some struct/class, but is rather a vector of pointers (or potentially some other object that acts like a pointer) to some struct/class. As such, to print the actual object, do `std::cout<<*alive[i]<<std::endl;` (note the added `*`).